# How to get any highest salary from SQL Server table

Tags: sql-server

How to get 7th highest salary from table in SQL Server?

I tried this:

```
SELECT max(salary)
FROM emptable
WHERE salary < (SELECT max(salary)
                FROM emptable);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT salary
FROM   (
            SELECT salary
            ,      DENSE_RANK()OVER(ORDER BY salary) DR
            FROM emptable
       ) T
WHERE  T.DR = 7
```

Answer (score 1):

From SQL Server 2012 and onwards:

```
SELECT DISTINCT salary
FROM emptable
ORDER BY salary
OFFSET 6 ROWS
FETCH NEXT 1 ROWS ONLY;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can as the below:

```
SELECT MAX(salary) 
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT TOP 7 salary FROM emptable ORDER BY salary) A
```